# NO Such File Error When Start a Bash Session

Tags: bash

Every time I start the terminal, there's an error prompt:

```
    Last login: Mon Apr  2 08:22:05 on ttys001find
    -bash: /Users/me/.nvm/nvm.sh: No such file or directory
```

I checked there's neither `/.nmv` in home directory

```
    $ ls ~/.nvm
    ls: /Users/me/.nvm: No such file or directory
    $ ls -a ~ | grep 'nvm'
    #return nothing
```

Nor in the root directory

```
    $ find /  -iregex '.*\.nvm.*' 2>/dev/null
    /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.NVMeAgent.plist
    /System/Library/Assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_ContextKit/005b384062d66f1a5bee19d879263a27f4d2c697.asset/AssetData/lucene.tagged.53.idx/_0.nvm
```

How to solve the problem, should I create a new `nvm.sh` file under `~/.nvm`

The environment variable

```
    $ echo $PATH
    /Users/me/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

Search your bash setup files.

On Linux, this would be ~/.bashrc, /etc/bash.bashrc ~/.profile and /etc/profile and files, sourced from these.

Maybe one of these references .nvm/nvm.sh, and maybe there is a comment, who placed it there for which reason.